# Can't login with rsa key on a Raspbian

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I've installed a Raspbian system, and would like to ssh to it using my private key. I use this key with other servers too, thus I'm sure chmod is set up well locally.

When I try to ssh to the Raspbian this happens:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/nagyviktor/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55c3847112d0), agent
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /home/nagyviktor/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug2: key: /home/nagyviktor/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/nagyviktor/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/nagyviktor/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nagyviktor/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/nagyviktor/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nagyviktor/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/nagyviktor/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

What should I change in my config to make the rsa key accepted?

Comment: packet type 51 is `SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE`.  You need to look at the logs on the server side to see _why_ your key is not accepted.  All the client will see is _that_ it is not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The key was rejected. That means you didn't set it up correctly on the server side. The easiest thing to do is

```
ssh-copy-id user@raspberry-ip
```

If you want to manually check the configuration, have a look into the owner and the permissions of all home directory, `~/.ssh/` directory and the `authorized_keys` file in there.